# Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/xml in xampp?

Tags: svg, xampp

I have a project without a .htaccess(I already found solutions when you have a .htaccess in your project) and it is not displaying my .svg. Normal images are displayed correctly. The error message is as follows:

```
Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/xml.
```

I am using xampp on osx yosemite version 10.10.1. Can I add

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

somewhere in my xampp?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I reinstalled xampp and that solved the problem. I will leave this open, in case people step over this problem again and one of the answers might be the right one.

Comment: Anything that can be put in .htaccess can also be put in your main Apache config file.  The last time I used xampp it was under `apache/conf` but you should consult the xampp documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll keep it in mind. It's really strange... Shouldnt it have the same error, when I open the image in a new tab? Because it works in another tab and it is just not working for this one project...

Comment: Is there an answer to this question, or is it a zombie?

Comment: I have a little problem... I reinstalled xampp then and it worked, so I sadly can't test it :-(

Comment: @FrederikWitte did my solution help? If so, I'd love it if you would consider upvoting and/or accepting :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can add the appropriate mime type definitions to the following location depending on your OS:

`xampp\apache\conf\mime.types` or `/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types`

Note that the config file you're looking for is called `mime.types`

The definition you'd want to add would be something like:

`image/svg+xml svg svgz`

More info:

[1. Thread on the topic](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=91676)

[2. Blog post on the topic](http://www.mindmyweb.com/enable-mp4-files-on-servers/)

Comment: Hey grill, as I wrote into my comment, I just reinstalled xampp and it worked for me again, so I sadly cannot check if your solution works or not